# yetishare -404 not found register, login etc files

Tags: php

I download and install yetishare file hosting script ..

The problem is that only index.php page is working Other pages(register, login, account etc.) here not here ..

How to solve that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your file registation,login,account that as same directory or not..`register.php or login.php and account.php that different directory`

then enter that directory path..

Comment: These pages are redirected by .htaccess or index.php.   .. But only index.html page is working, when i click on any other link its showing my website's main page, fomric.com......  But yetishare script is in share2 folder

Comment: that all file in same directory or not??

Comment: Not bro, these are saved to templates folder

Comment: Can i send u pics of that ?

Comment: Can u share ur wtsap nmbr ? Or msg me at 8397920020

Comment: How to approve ?

Comment: option ti give you approve approveedit and reject that type option is given to you...

Comment: No bro.. ,, but without pics u not understand by my problm

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using a hacked nulled copy of Yetishare. I would suggest you buy a copy then you wont see this problem.

Using a nulled copy is essentially the same as stealing.......